# How can we print coloured output of Ansible tasks when Ansible is run through a shell script?

Tags: bash, ansible

I have an Ansible playbook that is called from a bash script as show in the below snippet:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Name of script: execute_ansible

# Execute ansible playbook
ansible-playbook my_ansible_playbook
```

This script is executed as below:

```bash
bash execute_ansible
```

When executed with the above command, the Ansible playbook `my_ansible_playbook` is executed correctly. However, the colorised output that would have been displayed had the Ansible playbook been run from the command line directly is not visible.
Is there a way we can enable the colorised output to be visible when executed from the shell script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#ansible-force-color

You can either set the environment variable `ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR` to `True`, or set the config `defaults.force_color` to `True` in your ansible config file (local `ansible.cfg`, `~/.ansible.cfg` or `/etc/ansible/ansible.cfg`)