# How to keep colors in shell output in ansible

Tags: ansible

I need to execute command on server and show output on client using ansible, output contains colors (as shell escape sequences), and this colors provide important information. Executable prints colorful logs, but for mre I replaceid it with `ls --color`.

It there better way than piping ouput to postprocessor script or writing custom module?

I tried debug module and it didn't work.

```yaml
---
- name: Show colorful output
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name:
    shell:
      cmd: ls --color
    register: output
  - name:
    debug:
      var: output['stdout']
```

I also tried `debug: msg="{{ output.stdout }}"` and it didn't work either

Comment: In a test with `yaml` callback I'got as result `TASK [debug] **************
ok: [localhost] =>
  output['stdout']: |-
    [0m[01;34mtestfolder[0m
    test.yml`, right? I assume this isn't what you are looking for? You are interested in the "color" instead?

Comment: @U880D yes, I'm interested in readable colored output

Comment: Would the [Example](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html#examples) from [`diy` callback – Customize the output](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/diy_callback.html#examples) work for you? That's the only one which I am aware of which doesn't require a crafting an own / full Custom Callback Plugin.

Comment: A test with the setting from [How can we print colored output of Ansible task ...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68797706/6771046) did not delivered colored debug stdout output for me either.